# PhoneGAP Plugin for C++

Tags: cordova

How can one write a PhoneGap plugin to access C/C++ library.  I don't see any description of this capability. and yet C is the most readily available language across platforms.  Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you are on Android you would write a Java Plugin then use JNI to call the C code. You'd have to use a similar approach on the other platforms as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw this answer out there just incase someone was looking into Cordova plugins. From the Cordova Plugin Documentation "A Cordova plugin bridges a bit of functionality between the WebView powering a Cordova application and the native platform the Cordova application is running on. Plugins are composed of a single JavaScript interface used across all platforms, and native implementations following platform-specific Plugin interfaces that the JavaScript will call into. It should be noted that all of the core Cordova APIs are implemented using this exact architecture." So it is possible to bridge between native code and the Cordova application.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. Could you improve it by editing the most important parts into your answer?

Comment: That should be better. I am still researching this topic myself so as I gain more insight I will add to it.

Comment: Answers written in a convoluted style that do not actually answer the question are discouraged as well ;) ("native code" in your answer stands (in case of Android) for Java, not C++)

Comment: @EricBaril Did you make any progress on this ?

Comment: @john No haven't been working on any Cordova apps recently. I can edit the answer but Im not really on that trail anymore and may not have the best answer.